# Using ground vs virtual ground in a single-supply Sallen-Key low-pass filter

Tags: active-filter, virtual-ground

This is the filter in question (courtesy of Wikipedia):

[image]

The opamp supplies are +5 V and 0 V, and I'm already using a buffered 2.5 V reference elsewhere in the circuit. I'm debating whether or not to change the ground node at capacitor C2 into the 2.5 V virtual ground. Doing so seems intuitive to me since I'm dealing with a single-supply filter.

But then I realized that if I were dealing with a passive RC low pass filter, I would not connect its capacitor to a 2.5 V virtual ground even if the input signal had a DC offset of 2.5 V.

What should I keep in mind when making my decision? Is one option always better than the other (though perhaps sometimes negligibly so), or are there some cases were real ground is better and others were virtual ground is better? Note that this filter will be used in a high-precision application.

PS: I wanted to know what would happen if I modeled the C2 capacitor leakage current as a parallel resistance. As I lowered this resistance, the gain of the system became lower. Furthermore, using the 2.5 V virtual ground kept the output centered around 2.5 V, whereas using the normal ground did not (the output DC bias was scaled by the gain).

Answer (score 3):

C2 is a capacitor and, providing the "0V" point you connected it to has a low AC impedance and it has low noise compared to the input signals "ground" reference then it doesn't matter. DC doesn't pass through the capacitor to any great extent and any leakage can be reasonably ignored except in the most precision applications.

If the 5V power rail were clean you could connect C2 to that rail.

Comment: It will be used in a high-precision application. Given that's the case, should I connect the capacitor to real ground (0 V) or virtual ground (2.5 V)? Is one always better than the other  (though perhaps sometimes negligibly so), or are there some cases were real ground is better and others were virtual ground is better? I definitely won't connect it to 5 V.

Comment: Whatever ground reference point your input signal uses is the correct "ground" for connecting the capacitor to. This is the cleanest noise-free point.

Comment: By "ground reference point" do you mean 0 V or 2.5 V? (in the example provided above)

Comment: I'll try this again - where is your input voltage (Vin) referenced to i.e. where is its 0V? Wherever it is (either real 0V or some other 0V), that **IS** where you connect the capacitor for lowest noise interference.

Comment: So if the input voltage to my Sallen Key filter is the output from [this circuit](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/images/appnotes/656/E26Fig04.gif), would you connect the filter capacitor to 0 V or Vref?

Comment: I'm not trying to be obstinate here but you are missing the point about noise reduction. On that new circuit the output will have a large content of Vin and a smaller content of the AC noise between Vin's ground reference and Vref. So, basically it comes down to just pushing the problem further back and, to answer your question based on this new drawing I ask (almost a paraphrase of before), where is the ground reference for Vin?

Comment: If you can say that the ground reference for Vin is, as far as noise and signals concerned (but not necessarily DC), exactly the same as Vref then it doesn't matter. However, if the ground for Vin has some noise voltage differences to Vref (more than likely but not necessarily a showstopper) then using Vref may be a problem. Why do you think folk use differential amplifiers or even transformers to couple signals - it is to avoid this problem. You said "It will be used in a high-precision application" and I can only advise you what is the best. If you showed a diff amplifier then use Vref.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34633/discussion-between-sharphawk-and-andy-aka).

Comment: Diff input like this: http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/41-08/AD41-08-05.gif - the diagram on the right has a mid-rail bias like your Vref idea. In these scenarios Vref can be used for any subsequent signal 0V reference.

Comment: Sorry can't chat going bed in a mo!